# How can I solve the "Unable to find back camera" error?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to run a script that will display video from my webcam on my computer, but when I run it the error `unable to find back camera` pops up.

My webcam is hooked up and working, so as my other script, but this one doesn't do what I need it to do.

How can I fix this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MainCam : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool camAvailable;
    private WebCamTexture backCam;
    private Texture defaultBackground;

    public RawImage background;
    public AspectRatioFitter fit;

    private void Start()
    {
        defaultBackground = background.texture;
        WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;

        if (devices.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("No camera detected");
            camAvailable = false;
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < devices.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!devices[i].isFrontFacing)
            {
                backCam = new WebCamTexture(devices[i].name, Screen.width, Screen.height);
            }
        }

        if (backCam == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Unable to find back camera");
            return;
        }

        backCam.Play();
        background.texture = backCam;

        camAvailable = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!camAvailable)
            return;

        float ratio = (float)backCam.width / (float)backCam.height;
        fit.aspectRatio = ratio;

        float scaleY = backCam.videoVerticallyMirrored ? -1f: 1f;
        background.rectTransform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, scaleY, 1f);

        int orient = -backCam.videoRotationAngle;
        background.rectTransform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, orient);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you looking for a "back" camera on a PC? Wouldn't we expect PC webcams to generally be forward-facing?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have at least one back facing camera in the list? A simple `Debug.Log` inside `if (!devices[i].isFrontFacing)` body should do the trick.